# Vectorized alternative for swapping

Tags: r, loops, transform, vectorization

I am trying to use vectorized alternative of this code:

```
x=read.table("1.txt")
for(i in 1:nrowx)
{
  if(x[i,1]>x[i,2])             
  {
    temp=x[i,1]
    x[i,1]=x[i,2]
    x[i,2]=temp
    x[i,3]=(x[i,3]*(-1))
  }
}
```

I tried using transform function:

```
x <- transform(x, 
               x[[1]] <- ifelse(x[[1]]>x[[2]], x[[2]], x[[1]]), 
               x[[2]] <- ifelse(x[[1]]>x[[2]], x[[1]], x[[2]]),
               x[[3]] <- ifelse(x[[1]]>x[[2]], -x[[3]], x[[3]]))
```

However no success with it. The original file is returned with no operation performed.

Few lines of the file read in x:

```
"X1" "X2" "X3"
"1" 10 4 1440
"2" 10 4 3765
"3" 10 22 523
"4" 10 295 730
"5" 10 295 1599
"6" 10 584 1872
"7" 10 403 1872
"8" 10 403 1872
"9" 10 281 554
"10" 10 123 554
```

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: The syntax for `transform` is wrong. That function takes arguments like any other, hence the elements after the first argument should be of the form `foo = bar`, where `bar` is the object/result that will be included in the returned object and `foo` is the name to which it is assigned in the returned object. Perhaps you were thinking of `within()`? That function has syntax similar to what you show. Also, you don't need `transform` if you aren't referring to any object within `x` *by name`. Each of the three statements you include could all be done outside of `transform()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use `[` to subset the relevant rows, and `rev` to swap the columns ( and now `cbind` to include the column you want to also multiply by `-1`)... Of course this is now becoming a more complex and unreadable operation than I would like because you did not state fully your requirements in the OP. Please do so next time.

```
x[ x[,1] > x[,2] , 1:3 ] <- cbind( rev( x[ x[,1] > x[,2] , 1:2 ] ) , 
                                        x[ x[,1] > x[,2] , 3 ] * -1 )
#   X1  X2    X3
#1   4  10 -1440
#2   4  10 -3765
#3  10  22   523
#4  10 295   730
#5  10 295  1599
#6  10 584  1872
#7  10 403  1872
#8  10 403  1872
#9  10 281   554
#10 10 123   554
```

**@BenBolker** suggests creating an object from the subsetted rows to make more readable and efficient code...

```
swaprows <- x[,1] > x[,2]
x[swaprows,] <- cbind(rev(x[swaprows,1:2]),-x[swaprows,3])
```

Much better.

Comment: There's another operation that I need to perform along with swapping. The content of 3rd column needs to be multiplied by -1 whenever swapping is done. I have done the necessary editing in my original question.
Aplogies for not mentioning it earlier.

Comment: Can you please give the answer incorporating this as well.
thanks!

Comment: @phoenix jeez, you only commented 2mins ago. Hold you horses!

Comment: for readability, perhaps set `swaprows <- x[,1] > x[,2]` first, then `x[swaprows,] <- cbind(rev(x[swaprows,1:2]),-x[swaprows,3])` ?

Comment: @BenBolker that's a good idea and would indeed make the code more readable (and save some unnecessary time on repeating the same subsetting to boot). Good suggestion..

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `ifelse` but since you are doing the operation over the same variables its better you create the X1 and X2 as X4 and X5 and drop these in the end.

```
x$X4<-x$X1
 x$X5<-x$X2
 x$X1<-with(x,ifelse(X1>X2,X2,X1))
 x$X2<-with(x,ifelse(X4>X2,X4,X2))
 x$X3<-with(x,ifelse(X4>X5,-X3,X3))
 x$X4<-NULL
 x$X5<-NULL
> x
   X1  X2    X3
1   4  10 -1440
2   4  10 -3765
3  10  22   523
4  10 295   730
5  10 295  1599
6  10 584  1872
7  10 403  1872
8  10 403  1872
9  10 281   554
10 10 123   554
```